# Weblogic 10.3.6 Spring 3.2 @Autowired doesn't work

Tags: spring, weblogic

Not able to get Autowiring to work. Upgrading to Weblogic is not an option for our organization at this time. Below is what the browser displays when the web site is launched. Also, included relevant coding as illustration.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'acmeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.acme.data.AcmeDao com.acme.service.AcmeService.acmeDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.acme.data.AcmeDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="baseDao" class="com.acme.BaseDao" abstract="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDS" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oracleDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc-acme" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="service" class="com.acme.service.AcmeService">
        <property name="acmeDao" ref="acmeDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="acmeDao" class="com.acme.service.AcmeDao"
        parent="baseDao" /> 

</beans>
```

AcmeService.java:

```
package com.acme.service;

import com.acme.data.AcmeDao;
import com.acme.load.beans.ProviderEligibilityBean;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class AcmeService implements AcmeServiceInterface {

    final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AcmeService.class);

    @Autowired
    private AcmeDao acmeDao;
    public void setAcmeDao(AcmeDao acmeDao) {
        this.acmeDao = acmeDao;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in your AcmeService.class.

1)You imported com.acme.data.AcmeDao but you are referencing com.acme.service.AcmeDao in the context.xml.

2)You are setting com.acme.service.AcmeDao reference in AcmeService bean definition in context.xml

If you want to reference com.acme.service.AcmeDao, change import to com.acme.service.AcmeDao. Then, remove @Autowired annotation as you are already referencing this in context.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Prasad, but needed Autowired.  Got it to work by adding @Repository in AcmeDao. Not sure why. Also, temporarily added constructor in AcmeService to debug and make sure the class was instantiated. I saw other posting suggesting to use <context:component-scan base-package=... but it turned out it wasn't necessary.

Comment: @westcoastmilt Since acmeDao is specified both in xml config and annotation, I said annotation is not required as xml config will take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the full stack trace. Spring stack traces are very verbose and can be difficult to interpret if you don't pay attention. In particular, you may get an exception saying that an injection failed when the root cause is in fact that the bean to be injected could not be created.

This *will* be specified in the stack trace, but a little bit further down. In this case, for instance, one possible cause could be that the data source cannot be created, e.g. if the JNDI name is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by adding @Repository in AcmeDao. Not sure why that works.